# How to show .txt files in Xcode project navigator

Tags: c++, xcode

Is there any way to adjust Xcode so I can see the .txt files that I make using #include  ofstream outputFile; As in creating a .txt file in the environment and writing data to it, and also having it appear in my project navigator after it is done?

I have tried what previous users have said, which is clicking on the projectname > My Mac and selecting Edit Scheme -> Options -> Working Directory, however, I have to go to my finder to be able to see the file.  My goal here is to have it appear and update in the project navigator.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to have a txt file appear in Xcode's project navigator is to add the file to the project. Only files that have been added to the project appear in the project navigator. If your program creates txt files in the project's folder, those files won't appear in the project navigator.

Comment: What if you have a folder reference and write a text file into the directory it points to? Does Xcode automatically pick it up?

Comment: That might work. The OP should try it and report the findings.